# Facebook developer account verification

Tags: verification, facebook-developers

I’m trying to verify my account since a week now: I corrected the name and the date of birth, I gave them my phone number to enter a security code, and after all they asked me to upload a government issued ID. Now I’m waiting since a week and I didn’t get any response. Does somebody know how long this process usually takes and if there is anything I can do to speed it up?

Comment: Hm, I’ve found somebody apparently with the same problem: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7874654/facebook-developer-account-verify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is [this form](http://www.facebook.com/help/contact/?id=142315805886940) and all you need to be is patient and vigorous and in the end you even get an eMail response from an actual human begin.